# How to add querySelector in window.addEventListener in angular?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, addeventlistener, queryselector

i would like to add a close dropdown button in angular when user click outside? I use  window.addEventListener to detect user click outside or not. However, it seem to be use  document.querySelector cannot detect a element. How to deal with it ?

Here is what I've tried :

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let checkbox = document.querySelector('#delete-drop-down');

    window.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.el.nativeElement.checkbox.natveElement.checked = false;
    });

    window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
}
```

[here is stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scss-yiufze?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Use it in `ngAfterViewInit`, not in `constructor`

Comment: @Eugene Hi , I tried but not working

Comment: It is essential to include some piece of your code in your question that shows what you have tried so far. People should be able to understand it without leaving the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are using Angular you should get used to not using `document.querySelector` or `window.addEventListener`. Angular is here to encapsulate those things for you.

A proper implementation should include a `@HotsListener` for listening `document` or `window` click events. And some `@ViewChild` for accessing elements in the template. And `ngModel` to bind the checked value for the check box.

Here is what your `AppComponent` should look like :

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('check', { static: false })
  checkInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  @ViewChild('btn', { static: false })
  btnInput: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

  isDropDownOpen = false;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  windoClick($event: MouseEvent) {
    if (
      $event.target === this.checkInput.nativeElement ||
      $event.target === this.btnInput.nativeElement
    ) {
      console.log('skipping');
      return;
    }
    this.isDropDownOpen = false;
  }
}
```

And your component template should look like :

```
  <button class="button" #btn>Delete</button>

  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name=""
    [(ngModel)]="isDropDownOpen"
    id="delete-drop-down"
    #check
  />
  <label class="button dropdown-toggle" for="delete-drop-down">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </label>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scss-cpge85?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  @HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
  stopPropagation(event){
    console.log(document.querySelector('#delete-drop-down'))
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).